# CPU fan motor to power a small light bulb

Tags: power, motor, fan, electricity

Have you all heard about the **cpu fan** as a motor, that one with magnets, would it really work? And how *fast* does it need to spin to generate enough electricity for a small light bulb?

Comment: Any motor is a generator.  Spin it at its rated speed, it will generate its nominal rated voltage.  You didn't define "Small".  Or exactly what motor.  Very poor question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Google is the first place for this question.

Comment: CPU fans are usually brushless DC motors which don't just output DC.

Answer (score 6):

In general, every motor can work as a generator.

However, in your specific case, CPU fans are typically actual 3-Phase motors (like big, industrial motors) with electronics that generates the 3-Phase supply from the DC current it gets from the mainboard.

So, while the 3-Phase motor works as generator, this circuitry doesn't, and you simply can't use it as a generator.